# The program adds "" to the string I'm indexing

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using this piece of code

```
shares_one = [(None,), ('200 @ 496',), ('200 @ 486',)]
print(shares_one)
variable_one = StringVar(add_sale_quantity_selector)
variable_one.set(shares_one[1])  # default value
y = OptionMenu(add_sale_quantity_selector, variable_one, *shares_one)
y.place(x=25, y=40)
x = (variable_one.get())
bad_chars = ['"']
for i in bad_chars:
    test_string = x.replace(i, '')
print (test_string)
index = shares_one.index(test_string)
print(index)
```

but it gives me the following error

```
ValueError: "('200 @ 496',)" is not in list
```

for the line `index = shares_one.index(test_string)`

whats the possible solution, sorry if anythings out of the picture.

Comment: The `""` just indicate a string. They aren't part of the data that the strings holds.

Comment: so why isnt the code working

Comment: Because `get` returns a string, but `shares_one` it holding tuples. You'll need to either reparse `test_string` back to a tuple, convert the `shares_one` tuples into string, or use a more sophisticated method of checking than `index`

Comment: converting it into tuple, converts it into literal separate one one letters

Comment: `StringVar` *only* holds a string; when you pass the tuple as an argument to `set`, its `__str__` method is used to create a string from it.

Comment: `variable_one.get()` will return a string, perhaps you are looking for `variable_one.set(shares_one[1][0])` and then `x = (variable_one.get(),)` and then `index = shares_one.index(test_string)`. But this all happens in a single stretch, I do not understand why you need a `StringVar` for this.

Comment: could you maybe edit the code and send me? Im new at this and cant understand you completely

Comment: Basically this is a list that is derived form a mysql column and then I wanna index the whole column using a drop down and then use the Index to get all the things in that particular row